# Is it Worth it to Upgrade the Clan Castle

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was wondering if the clan castle building is worth the resources to upgrade it.  I rarely attack getting all my resources from farming and use all them for upgrading defenses.

I'm questioning the clan castle and it's ability to be used as defense.  The troops that leave the castle during an attack seem really weak and feel wasted.  But I also keep requesting troops from my clan mates because I don't know if it would help defend my base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always upgrade everything to the max with every Town hall level.

The Clan Castle should be considered amongst your higher upgrade priorities. Increasing its capacity will significantly improve your defensive strength. However, it is not your number one upgrade. It is usually a better use of builders to grab brand new structures and buildings while focusing upgrades on the Laboratory.

Imagine the Clan Castle as the strongest defensive tower, it should be upgraded first before you upgrade any other old towers, but upgrading other structures and setting up an appropriate base layout for your Town Hall level takes precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Its worth upgrading Clan Castle, when u reach new Town Hall level one of first things to do is upgrade clan castle because it helps in offence as well as defense for example: level 3 clan castle can hold powerful dragon. which u can use while attacking or it will defend your village when somebody attacks

Answer (score 2):

Only if you are regularly participating in Clan Wars. If not, it's not a big deal. A few extra archers from your clan mates in an attack, meh.

Of course if you are doing wars, then it should probably be upgraded before any defensive structures as this raises your offensive capabilities a lot! You can get donated a Dragon (20 spaces), Pekka (25), or Golem/LavaHound(30) from higher level players to totally destroy bases you're up against.

Comment: So a Dragon/Pekka/Golem/LavaHound is valuable in clan war, but not in a regular attack? The issue is probably that high level clan mates are more eager to donate powerfull troops in a clan war scenario. But even high level cheap troops from higher level members can boost your capacity considerably in attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If higher level members of your clan are willingly donating, it will be very valuable for defence. Even archers are very good defence if they are high level compared to your own (and usuallly then also your attackers). The higher level your clan castle is, the more troops you can hold. Specially an upgrade to level 3 castle is a boost, since it then can hold dragon.

Another thing is if you participate in clan wars, the clan castle is holding all your resource loot you get in the clan wars. If you loot more in the clan war than the clan castle can hold, you will not get everything you earned in the war. Each upgrade will increase the amount of resources you can collect in the clan war.

Edit
After recent game update you also have the star bonus that is stored in the castle storage.